# Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle' when using spring-boot:1.5.1 and spring-cloud-stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I get the below mentioned error when using spring-boot:1.5.1 but not when using spring-boot:1.4.4

Has anyone encountered this?

```
package org.test;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class EtestSmsConsumerApplication {

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void readSms(SmsRequest smsRequest) {
        System.out.println("Received sms " + smsRequest);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EtestSmsConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Data
@ToString
class SmsRequest {
    private String message;
}
```

APPLICATION properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=sms
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=smsGroup2
server.port=8083
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>etest-sms-consumer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>etest-sms-consumer</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.M1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Exception thrown

**org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.test.EtestSmsConsumerApplication.main(EtestSmsConsumerApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationMessageListener.(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:191) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:338) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:202) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindInputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:208) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

Comment: Had a similar issue while using Rabbit instead of Kafka, turned out it is a known issue. Refer: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an inconsistency between the `Chelsea.M1` release of the binder and Spring Initializr - the Kafka binder starter requires the 0.9 dependency set as a baseline, but the Spring Boot parent overrides the Spring Kafka dependency to 1.1.2. Since Spring Integration Kafka is not managed by Spring Boot, the version that's pulled in by the binder - 2.0.1 - is incompatible to Spring Kafka 1.1.2.

Tracking this here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/88

Update: If using version `Spring Boot 1.5.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and later in Initializr, the proper dependency set should be retrieved. Note that a Kafka 0.10.1.x is required.

Comment: What's the fix though? Neither this answer nor the github issue mentions this fix.

Answer (score 1):

See the [recent chat in Gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream?at=5890d445c0f28dd86268974f).

Boot uses spring-kafka 1.1.2 and the 0.10.x.x kafka client.

You are pulling in an old spring-integration-kafka (2.0.x) which uses an old 1.0.x spring-kafka (for the 0.9.x.x kafka client).

To use boot 1.5.1, you need spring-integration-kafka 2.1.0, spring-kafka 1.1.2 and the 0.10.x.x kafka client.

The gitter chat points at this documentation [Using the binder with Apache Kafka 0.10](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_the_binder_with_apache_kafka_0_10).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue for boot and cloud integration, used Greenwich.SR1 spring cloud version and 2.1.3.RELEASE springboot version. Below gradle for it

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.SR1')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Comment: I experienced the same issue for spring-cloud-stream 2.2.0.RELEASE, using Confluent's Kafka/Zookeeper 5.2.2. Kafka clients 2.0.0. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency worker for me.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:2.1.2.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```