# Failed to stop bean 'inputBindingLifecycle' with Spring Boot 2.1.5, Spring Cloud Stream Greenwich.SR1 and RocketMQ 0.9.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, rocketmq

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986162/failed-to-start-bean-inputbindinglifecycle-when-using-spring-boot1-5-1-and-sp), but it's for an older version. Not sure what the conflicting version is for me, and what I need to use.

I used Spring Initializr to create my project, following the SCS Reference [Quick Start](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_quick_start). That set me up with my current versions (2.1.5, Greenwich.SR1).

The only dependency I added manually was for RocketMQ, since Spring Initializr couldn't find it. Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rocketmq</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error in question happens when I try to shut down the application, a process which takes nearly a minute each time. Here's the full stack trace when I shut down the app:

> Failed to stop bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress     at
>   java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.remove(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:82)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.lang.Runtime.removeShutdownHook(Runtime.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>     at
>   org.apache.rocketmq.client.trace.AsyncTraceDispatcher.removeShutdownHook(AsyncTraceDispatcher.java:210)
>   ~[rocketmq-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]    at
>   org.apache.rocketmq.client.trace.AsyncTraceDispatcher.shutdown(AsyncTraceDispatcher.java:183)
>   ~[rocketmq-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]    at
>   org.apache.rocketmq.client.consumer.DefaultMQPushConsumer.shutdown(DefaultMQPushConsumer.java:598)
>   ~[rocketmq-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rocketmq.consuming.RocketMQListenerBindingContainer.stop(RocketMQListenerBindingContainer.java:175)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rocketmq-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:0.9.0.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rocketmq.integration.RocketMQInboundChannelAdapter.doStop(RocketMQInboundChannelAdapter.java:128)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rocketmq-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:0.9.0.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.stop(AbstractEndpoint.java:173)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinding.stop(DefaultBinding.java:127)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinding.unbind(DefaultBinding.java:159)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.unbindConsumers(BindingService.java:303)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.unbindInputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:307)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStopWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:66)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.stop(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:56)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.stop(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.stop(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:73)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.stop(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:238)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:377)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:210)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:128)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1018)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945)
>   [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use version 0.2.1.RELEASE for the RocketMQ binder:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rocketmq</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```